# What is the difference between "too much choice" and "too many choices"?

Tags: grammatical-number

"that too much choice makes you unhappy,"

Anderson, Chris. TED Talks: The Official TED Guide to Public Speaking (Kindle Location 1295). Houghton Mifflin Harcourt. Kindle Edition.

vs. "that too many choices make you unhappy,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that they are very similar, but that you can at least draw a semantic distinction between the two. "Too many choices" indicates that one has been given a set of discreet options that is too large to be manageable. Whereas "too much choice" is more along the lines that you have too much freedom within a given set of parameters. So for example if you have to choose a college from all of the colleges in the United States, you might say that you suffer from too many choices because the list of possible options is very large. On the other hand, if you are ordering a burger and you have to decide where exactly you want each sesame seed to be placed on top of the bun, you suffer from too much choice. Too much choice means that you have too high a degree of freedom at too high a level of specificity. Too many choices means that you have lots of options are rendered unable to choose one because of the sheer quantity of options. "Too many choices" is analogous to being at a 50 way intersection and trying to figure out which way to go. "Too much choice" is a question of being too in the weeds of choice and losing sight of the forest for the trees. That being said, you could probably find them used more or less interchangeably as they are not *that* different.